# How often was this term googled?

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to find out how many times a certain term has been searched for in a certain timeframe?

Answer (score 7):

I've found this page on [Google Keyword Planner](https://ads.google.com/aw/keywordplanner/home).

You can filter on time and location.

You can see more information if you have an AdWords account.

> Sign in with your AdWords login information to see the full set of ideas for this search

Answer (score 0):

You could try Google Trends or the new [Google Insights for Search](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=pasta%2Cbears&date=today%201-m&cmpt=q). They won't give you absolute numbers though, just comparisons.

There are scads of dodgy-looking SEO tools out there that do purport to give you more exact numbers. If you decide to buy any of them, you should consider trying the V1@gra I'm selling first.